# IIS 7.5 site displays page cannot be displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, application-pool

Yesterday I was setting up a new site the same way I always do and when I went to test it I was at first getting error 503 and the application pool would stop for the site when that page was displayed.

Today its no longer displaying the 503 error and is now displaying page cannot be displayed. Also the application pool is no longer stopping.

I checked the Event Viewer and its getting the following error whenever I try to get onto the site:
A process serving application pool 'CP4_ICEGROUP' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '8136'. The data field contains the error number.

I have many sites that I have set up previous to this and they work fine. I have tried creating a different site since but that also wont work.

I have installed debugdbg and created a dump file and read it with the debugdbg analysis but was unable to find what is causing the problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set up the user login for the database for the site wrongly!